# best way to handle multiple login method from android

Tags: php, android, symfony, oauth, facebook-login

We are building an app (android for now, but later on other platforms) which needs the user to sign up by registering standard information like its email, username and password.

To simplify this step, we whish to allow the user to login via facebook or other social network through OAuth, but also to keep the possibility to create an account directly on our server by filling a form.

Now, we're struggling on finding the best way to do that:
-Should we use the facebook (or other) login to get the user information on the client and then create an account with these information with the same method than our standard form?
-Should we use the facebook login to get the access_token and send it to the server that creates an account itself, and use a different method for our own signup method?
-Something else?

Our main question is about the necessity of using OAuth on the server side for something else than the social network logins.

While many applications use such methods, it seems hard to find any exhaustive information on it...
So any help on that subject would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-Should we use the facebook login to get the access_token and send it to the server that creates an account itself, and use a different method for our own signup method? -
```

This method is better for three primary reasons:

1. You can change the logic whenever you want to.
2. You don't need update the app.
3. Sharing and activity logging on Social platforms become seamless as you don't rely on users' internet connection.
   And many more....